# Can you identify this 1x1 red hemisphere?

Tags: part-identification

Can you identify this red 1x1 hemisphere. It has a cross inside so it looks like it's made to fit on the end of an axle. 1x2 masonry brick added for sizing reference.

[image: 1x2 masonry brick added for size reference]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a “VOODOO BALL Ø10,2” -

Element ID: 4290714
Design ID: [32474](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32474)

Notable used in the recent LEGO Christmas wreath set to represent holly berries.

Comment: thanks: found it  https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32474#T=C&C=86

Comment: no problem but thanks